# Using auto layout at the expense of having no frame

Tags: ios, swift

I have a box that is initiated without a frame so it has 0 center and size.

```
let blackBox = UIView()
blackBox.backgroundColor = .blackColor()
blackBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(blackBox)
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: blackBox, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.1, constant: 0))
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: blackBox, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0))
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: blackBox, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: blackBox, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

Is there anyway to insert a centered subview into the `blackBox` **without** using autolayout or is there a **neater** way I could/should use it. The only way I can see this happening is:

```
let blueBox = UIView()
blackBox.addSubview(blueBox)
blueBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
blueBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: blueBox, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: blackBox, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: blueBox, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: blackBox, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: blueBox, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: blackBox, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.4, constant: 0))
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: blueBox, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: blackBox, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0.4, constant: 0))
```

Comment: Why not use auto layout?

Comment: What is wrong with the code / approach you show?

Comment: You can add the subview to your blackBox and set the frame in `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: The way I do is usually decide a frame for the view, and then use it as a origin to decide the frame, height, width for other views in correspondence to the screen I will be running on. Get h/w of screen `UIScreen().mainScreen.bounds` and then do some calculations to decides frame for view.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use `var bluebox = UIView(frame: CGRECT)` and set the `CGRect` accordingly.